# Uniqueness Theorem for ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $g:[0, T]\times\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Consider the Cauchy problem
 $$\begin{cases}x'(t)=g(t,x) \quad a.e \quad s\in [0, T]\\
x(0)=a\end{cases}$$
where $g(t,x)$ is continuous in $t$, locally Lipschitz in $x$ and has linear growth in $x$. The problem has a unique solution $x(.)$ on $[0, T]$ with locally Lipschitz dependence on initial data.

But I can't find any uniqueness theorem for ODE to cite. Would you please give me a reference?

Answer (score 2):

You want the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). It guarantees both the local existence and the uniqueness of the solution. You can also use this to prove global uniqueness for your system.